# document.dispatchEvent() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm having this problem where the `element.dispatchEvent(e);` isn't working properly in Firefox.

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLcy9xqg/) example I'm having trouble with.

The `element.dispatchEvent(e);` fires, and returns `true` but the desired event/effect doesn't happen, in the fiddle case, the opening of a `select` dropdown.

It works fine with Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.134 m).
I'm using Firefox 39.0 to test this, don't know if this is the case with older versions or just the new one.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

This may not be the complete answer, since there are a lot of differences in the way broswer handle select elements and events, but part of the issue may be attributed to `isTrusted` property of the `Event` object. See here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

You can see there's already a difference between browser regarding this:

> In Firefox, an event is trusted if it is invoked by the user and not
>   trusted if it is invoked by a script.
>
> In Internet Explorer, all events are trusted except those that are
>   created with the createEvent() method.
>
> Chrome does not support this property.

And if you look at what `isTrusted` means:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120614/#trusted-events

> Events that are generated by the user agent, either as a result of
>   user interaction, or as a direct result of changes to the DOM, are
>   trusted by the user agent with privileges that are not afforded to
>   events generated by script through the
>   DocumentEvent.createEvent("Event") method, modified using the
>   Event.initEvent() method, or dispatched via the
>   EventTarget.dispatchEvent() method. The isTrusted attribute of trusted
>   events has a value of true, while untrusted events have a isTrusted
>   attribute value of false.
>
> Most untrusted events should not trigger default actions, with the
>   exception of click or DOMActivate events. These events trigger the
>   default action of an activation trigger (see Activation triggers and
>   behaviors for more details); these untrusted events have an isTrusted
>   attribute value of false, but still initiate any default actions for
>   backwards compatibility. All other untrusted events must behave as if
>   the Event.preventDefault() method had been called on that event.

So basically, a script-generated event, in Firefox at least, doesn't necessarily behave exactly like a user-generated event. You can use it to trigger default behaviors, such as checking a checkbox or following a link, but in many case it won't do the same thing as actually generating the event through the interface. It'll be fired, but with restrictions.

Again, maybe there's a way to achieve what you're trying, I'm not totally sure that this is the cause of this specific issue, but it's pretty clear from the specs that mimicking user interactions through scripts isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: In other words, incompetent design and/or implementation by Mozilla and yet another bug I *won't* file because even if a super-high quality bug report *isn't* marked as a duplicate of a severely incompetent and completely unlegible bug report **Mozilla doesn't fix bugs**! This coming from someone who has filed *dozens of bugs over the past decade*.